# Replace string with ruby code

Tags: ruby

I worte an simple programm to replace text within (( )) with the user input:
If i have for example this this text:

```
i hab an terrible ((userinput1)) last ((userinput2)) in a horrible ((userinput3))
```

I tried first to replace the (( with #{ and the )) with }

```
str1 = gets.chomp
str2 = str1.clone

a = 0

begin
s = str2.index('((', a)
str2[s..s+1] = '#{'
a = a + s + 1
end until str2.length < a

b = 0

begin
s = str2.index('))', b)
str2[s..s+1] = '}' 
b = b + s + 1
end until str2.length < b

userinput1 = gets.chomp
userinput2 = gets.chomp
userinput3 = gets.chomp

puts str2
```

But somehow ruby dont validates the userinputs, instead i get:

```
i hab an terrible #{userinput1} last #{userinput2} in a horrible #{userinput}
```

I think the problem is that in my code i wrote:

```
str2[s..s+1] = '#{'
```

instead of

```
str2[s..s+1] = "#{"
```

because so all my remaining code is an object until it is closed with }. SO what can i do ? I hope you understood my issue?

```
str1 = gets.chomp

word = str1.scan(/\(\(\w+\)\)/)

word.each do |word|
str1.gsub(word, "what the fuck")
end

puts str1
```

Comment: You need to `eval()` that string or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice try. But there's a simpler way. Much simpler :) Basically, you just have to collect user inputs. There are methods for replacing string parts already.

```
userinput1 = gets.chomp
userinput2 = gets.chomp
userinput3 = gets.chomp

template = "i had a terrible ((userinput1)) last ((userinput2)) in a horrible ((userinput3)"

result = template.gsub('((userinput1))', userinput1).
                  gsub('((userinput2))', userinput2).
                  gsub('((userinput3))', userinput3)
              #    ^^ replacing happens here    
puts result
```

Comment: Sorry but the content between the (( )) changes, so that i cant use simply userinput1,2,3

Comment: How can i gsub for example between [0..7]?

Comment: Ah, so it's dynamic as well? No problem. You have to [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) through the string and find placeholders. Then you ask users for values and do the substitution.

Comment: And how has to be the statement for the scan? I tried something with puts str1.scan(/(())/) but wont work?

Comment: It has to be a Reqular Expression. Try this: `str1.scan(/\(\(\w+\)\)/)`

Comment: Do you know an website where i can learn more abput Regular Expression and ruby?

Comment: I edited my question, with code that i tried, but that wont work! Can you help me out?